# Finding the position of search hits from Lucene using python

Tags: python

```
search_results=es.search(index='travel', doc_type='books',
                        body={"_source":"name",
                              'query':{
                            "match":{"content":"time to travel in data science"}},
                                                              })

[{match: "travel ", startIndex: 10, length: 3},
 {match: "science", startIndex: 34, length: 3}]
```

I am searching `queries` in **pdf** documents using `python elasticsearch as shown above snippet code. Now, I want to extract the paragraph or position(location) where it matched. Can anyone guide how to find the position of the matched query (sentence), so that I can extract the matched paragraph. Any early help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.